# SVG to PNG - lines invisible

Tags: svg, imagemagick, line, inkscape, invisible

Problem:
some svg drawings open well in chrome and edge but not in inkscape or do not convert well with imagemagick. In my case only the text-labels were shown, no lines or drawings at all.

I could not find a solution on stack-overflow or google, the problem seems to occur with others to, but with no answer why and/or with no solution

Comment: Please include an example of a SVG that doesn't render correctly. One issue could be that it is only browsers that render CSS. Try converting CSS to native SVG attribute styling.

Comment: @chrwahl : please find an example here: https://melitta.ricambio.net/ce/001/CE_2432_1.SVG . You'll notice that it shows correctly in the browser, but not in inkscape and imagemagick. See my answer below why and how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, I found the reason why: the colors in my SVG were speficied like this:

```
stroke:RGB(0,0,0);
```

According to the SVG spefication, this seems ok, only the specs mention 'rgb' in lower case.
When I converted 'RGB' to 'rgb' in my drawings, they were processed correctly in chrome, edge, inkscape and imagemagick

My correction in C# as inspiration:

```
var allText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
allText = Regex.Replace(allText, @"RGB\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)", @"rgb($1,$2,$3)");
File.WriteAllText(fileName, allText);
```